# Deeply nested object.reduce

Tags: javascript, reduce

I'm trying to reduce a deeply nested object but getting errors. I have a flat array of objects that include a player_id, character_id, scenario_id, and a boolean field. I'm trying to make the resulting object look like this:

```
player_id: {
  scenario_id: {
    played: {
      character_id1: true,
      character_id2: true,
    },
  },
}
```

My reduce statement is:

```
const arr = [
  {
    player_id: 1,
    scenario_id: 1,
    character_id: 1,
    played: true,
  },
  {
    player_id: 1,
    scenario_id: 2,
    character_id: 2,
    played: true,
  },
];

arr.reduce((prev, next) => {
  if (!prev[next.player_id]) {
    prev[next.player_id] = {};
  }
  prev[next.player_id] = {
    ...prev[next.player_id],
    [next.scenario_id]: {
      ...prev[next.player_id][next.scenario_id],
      played: next.played ? {
        ...prev[next.player_id][next.scenario_id].played,
        [next.character_id]: true,
      } : {},
   };
    return prev;
 }, {});
```

When I run this, I get an error saying it can't read property played of undefined.

Any thoughts?

Comment: could you write source array and desired result?

Comment: Your desired resulting object won't work as there are duplicates `scenario_id`s and you only have one in the resulting object.

Comment: @stepup I have the array in the code and the desired resulting object.@ibrahimmahrir, this totally works without the played piece of the object. I get multiple scenario_ids as keys of the player_id object that gets created.